# Perl Structures into array

Tags: perl, file, structure

one simple question, but I couldn't find the solution anywhere.
I have a text file which consists of students, lets say, and looks like this:

```
1 bob smedley 4
2 rob nielsen 7
3 sol connie 9
4 jon sidney 18
```

Then I have a structure Student, that looks like this:

```
struct Student => {ID => '$', name  => '$', surname => '$', points => '$',};
```

I loaded this text file into an array using: `@stud = <inFILE>;`

And now I want to load each row from my `@stud` into an array of Student structures. Let's call it `my @students;` so that 
for example, my first structure looks like this:

```
id = 1;
name = bob;
surname = smedley;
points = 4;
```

And do that for every row in `@stud`.
Alternatively, I could load those structures directly from file, but I was thinking it might be easier using temp array @stud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to slurp the file into an array. You can process it line by line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Class::Struct;
struct Student => {ID => '$', name  => '$', surname => '$', points => '$',};

my @students;

while (<>) {
    my ($id, $name, $surname, $points) = split;
    my $s = Student->new;
    $s->ID($id);
    $s->name($name);
    $s->surname($surname);
    $s->points($points);
    push @students, $s;
}
```

Comment: @Whizzil: Remove the prototypes.

Comment: @Whizzil: Read [perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub) and [Far More Than Everything You've Ever Wanted to Know about Prototypes in Perl](http://users.telenet.be/bartl/classicperl/prototypes/fmproto.html).